# ASP MVC Multiple-Button Form Let JQuery Intercept a Button Click

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I created a multiple-button form based on the solution found [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/939b56/handling-multiple-submit-buttons-on-the-same-form-in-Asp-Net/).

I need jQuery to intercept one of the button's click event and submit it manually after presenting with a modal dialog box. However, when I tried using type="button" the value of command in controller became null. I also tried using preventDefault() in my javascript file instead but same thing happens.

In my view:

```
<input id="action1" type="submit" name="command" value="Action One" />
<input id="action2" type="submit" name="command" value="Action Two" />
```

In my controller:

```
if (command == "Action One")
{
    // Do something
}
else if (command == "Action Two")
{
    // Do something else
}
```

In my javascript:

```
$('#action1').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    showModalDialog();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround you can try the folloing:

1. Assign the same CSS `class` attribute to both your buttons.
2. Replace `type="submit"` with `type="button"`.
3. Add a jQuery click event to the `css` name which will fire when either of the two buttons are clicked.Store the clicked button value in a variable
4. Display the modal popup and after the user clicks on "OK" call the controller action passing through the value of the clicked button.

May sound like a lot of work but it's really simple.Just copy and paste the code below into your solution and run it.Understand how it works and apply to your own solution.

**View:**

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Command</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var command = "";

            $(".command").click(function () {
                command = $(this).val();
                $(".modal-body").empty();
                $(".modal-body").html("You selected command - " + command + ".Press OK call the controller...");
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
            });

            $("#btnOK").click(function () {
                $.getJSON("/Command/MyCommand?command=" + command, function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input class="command" type="button" id="action1" name="command" value="Action One" />
    <input class="command" type="button" id="action2" name="command" value="Action Two" />
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal Header</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button id="btnOK" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Controller:**

```
public class CommandController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public JsonResult MyCommand(string command)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        return Json(command + " is complete.", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Denis. I will try your solution.